# Android Studio and GitLab

Tags: android, git, gitlab

I work with my team in a project which is registered in GitLab.
Every time that I am trying to open my project with android studio it pops up a message

`"Unregistered VCS root detected
The directory C:\...\...\ is under Git, but is not registered in the Settings."`

And below this message I have three options

1.Add root

2.Configure

3.Ignore

Every time I press add root and then it appears the button in the taskbar with which I can pull the changes from that have made to the code.

Is any option to change so, this message will not appear any more.

Thank you and BR.

Comment: It should only do that once, when it opens the project for the first time